# mongo db keeps waiting for connection on port 27017

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run mongodb version 4, from command prompt on windows10. when I give the commond "mongod --dbpath ", it starts to connect and then waits to connecton port 27017.
Then I open another command prompt window and execute the command "mongo" to run the server. This gets connected and I can confirm by using the "show dbs" command.

BUT, the previous command prompt window still shows that it is waiting to connect to port 27017, even after an hour!!

Please help.
Regards,
SV

Comment: Mongod is a server, so it can accept more that one connection and will waiting new connections until termination.

Comment: ohh , so it means even if doesn't gives me a message about connection established, its fine and working, I should not worry about it, right? I am trying to learn on my own and was trying to connect to very first time, so I am a bit apprehensive about it.